# Viewing the source code behind python modules such as Pandas and Random

Tags: python, pandas, random

I would like to see how to view the code behind these modules, such as how `randint` from `random` works, etc.

```
import pandas
import random
```

For example:

```
print(pandas.file)
print(random.file)
```

Answer (score 1):

The source code for most built-in Python modules is located on GitHub, in the [python/cpython](https://github.com/python/cpython) repository.

The source code for third-party modules (which is what pandas is) can typically be found on a link on their PyPI page (`https://pypi.org/project/<module name>`).

For example:

- [`pandas` module source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas) (from [here](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/))
- [`random` module source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/random.py) (from [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/main/Lib))

---

Many modules, such as pandas, are actually a large collection of files, so there is not one file containing every function.

In some cases, however, you can use `inspect.getsource` (a Python built-in function) to return a string containing the source code for the object:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> import random
>>> print(inspect.getsource(random))
"""Random variable generators.

    bytes
    -----
           uniform bytes (values between 0 and 255)

    integers
    --------
           uniform within range

    sequences
    ---------
           pick random element
           pick random sample
           pick weighted random sample
           generate random permutation

.....
```

Answer (score 0):

This will print the file path on your machine where Python is importing those modules from.

```
import pandas
import random
print(pandas.__file__)
print(random.__file__)
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\xxxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py
C:\Users\xxxx\Anaconda3\lib\random.py
```

You can go to those files and view the source code.

Comment: I believe `inspect.getsource` reads those very files, right? :)

Comment: @richardec Nice! I hadn't heard of that before.